# Read JSON Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I'm trying to read department array in python. I can read the first element of the array. how can I read the rest for example the values for "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"? Any suggestions?

```
import json


person2 = '{"FirstName":"2018 Q1 (JAN-MAR)","LastName":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","Phone":"2222222222222222","Department":[{"cpt":"A0001","aaa":"1","bbb":"2","ccc":"3","ddd":"4","eee":"5"},{"cpt":"A0002","aaa":"6","bbb":"7","ccc":"8","ddd":"9","eee":"10"},{"cpt":"A0003","aaa":"11","bbb":"21","ccc":"31","ddd":"44","eee":"55"},{"cpt":"A0004","aaa":"101","bbb":"22","ccc":"33","ddd":"44","eee":"55"},{"cpt":"A0005","ffs":"100","mmc":"23","med":"34","oth":"45","duo":"56"},{"cpt":"A0006","aaa":"111","bbb":"24","ccc":"34","ddd":"44","eee":"54"}],"checkAgree":true}'
person_dict = json.loads(person2)


#Example of how to read JSON array elements in python
print(person_dict['Department'][0]["cpt"]);

print(person_dict['Department'][1]["cpt"]);

print(person_dict['Department'][3]["cpt"]);

print(person_dict['Department'][4]["cpt"]);

print(person_dict['Department'][5]["cpt"]);
```

> ```
> "Department": [
>     {
>       "cpt": "A0001",
>       "aaa": "1",
>       "bbb": "2",
>       "ccc": "3",
>       "ddd": "4",
>       "eee": "5"
>     },
>     {
>       "cpt": "A0002",
>       "aaa": "6",
>       "bbb": "7",
>       "ccc": "8",
>       "ddd": "9",
>       "eee": "10"
>     },
>     {
>       "cpt": "A0003",
>       "aaa": "11",
>       "bbb": "21",
>       "ccc": "31",
>       "ddd": "44",
>       "eee": "55"
>     },
>     {
>       "cpt": "A0004",
>       "aaa": "101",
>       "bbb": "22",
>       "ccc": "33",
>       "ddd": "44",
>       "eee": "55"
>     },
>     {
>       "cpt": "A0005",
>       "aaa": "100",
>       "bbb": "23",
>       "ccc": "34",
>       "ddd": "45",
>       "eee": "56"
>     },
>     {
>       "cpt": "A0006",
>       "aaa": "111",
>       "bbb": "24",
>       "ccc": "34",
>       "ddd": "44",
>       "eee": "54"
>     }
>   ],
> ```

Comment: What happens if you try to read the other elements in the `Department` other than cpt?
`print(person_dict['Department'][0]["aaa"]);`
`print(person_dict['Department'][0]["bbb"]);`
etc.

Comment: What did you try to access these fields, and how did it go wrong?

Comment: I forgot to try that! @chrisbyte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the name of the element you are looking for

```
print(person_dict['Department'][0]["aaa"])
print(person_dict['Department'][0]["bbb"])
print(person_dict['Department'][0]["ccc"])
```

etc.

You can also do this in a loop depending on what you are trying to achieve, just as an example

```
def get_attr(elem, attr):
  if attr in elem:
    return elem[attr]
  return ''

for e in person_dict['Department']:
  print('%s %s %s %s' % (get_attr(e, 'cpt'), get_attr(e, 'aaa'), get_attr(e, 'bbb'), get_attr(e, 'ccc')))
```

Outputs:

```
A0001 1 2 3
A0002 6 7 8
A0003 11 21 31
A0004 101 22 33
A0005
A0006 111 24 34
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat the code you simply must pass the `key`. Consider you have a dictionary that contains lists and dictionaries within that lists, you shouldn't treat it in any different way:

```
for i in range(len(person_dict['Department'])):
   for k in person_dict['Department'][i]:
       print("Key =",k,"Value =",person_dict['Department'][i][k])
```

This will output:

```
Key = cpt Value = A0001
Key = aaa Value = 1
Key = bbb Value = 2
Key = ccc Value = 3
Key = ddd Value = 4
Key = eee Value = 5
```

... And so on

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through all the elements:

```
for d in person_dict['Department']:
    for k,v in d.items():
        print("Key =", k ,"Value =", v)
```